# finding the dimension of a set with a measure of zero.

Tags: real-analysis

$ X = \{r \epsilon [0,1]$ : r has a decimal expansion with no 4's}.

I already solved that the measure of X is zero. How do I find the dimension of it?

Comment: What is your definition of dimension?

Comment: Hausdorff dimension?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Answer (score 2):

If by dimension you mean Hausdorff dimension, then the answer is

$$\frac{\log 9}{\log 10}=\log_{10}9\approx 0.95$$

The proof is similar with the one [here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F11/hausdorff.pdf). Except that you take out intervals of length $1/10$ instead of $1/3$ as it is done in the proof for the Cantor set.

Comment: Oh I see. So for every decimal excluded, the numerator goes down from log(x) to log(x-1)?

Comment: That is the case indeed.